# What is the right past tense usage of a verb "Learn"?

Tags: verbs, indian-english

I have a doubt for a long days.Today I got a chance to clear it.

What is the right Past tense usage of a verb "Learn"?

Is it Learnt or Learned?

Answer (score 0):

Both of them. "Learnt" is more British, though.